# Mocha sinon.spy always showing function call 0 times

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai, spy

I am new to mocha/chai. I am trying to write the unit test case for following scenario. I want to test whether "callchildfunc" and "childfunc2" is called or not upon calling "parent()" function.

I have read the fundamental and what I understood is if you are spying on any function then just put assert on that function to check if that function is called or not. Means in above script file If i will spy on "childfunc2" and "callchildfunc" function then I don't need to call here in test file since it is already called in script file under parent function. Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

This is my script.js file

```
// script.js    

function childfunc2(){
    console.log("child function without return");
}
function callchildfunc(var1, var2){
   return var1 + var2;
}
function parent(x){
   var getreturnval = callchildfunc(x, 1);
   console.log(getreturnval);
   childfunc2();
}
```

This is my test file.

```
//scenario 1

describe('Test for parent() function ', function(){
   it('should make parent call ', function(){

        var spy1 = sinon.spy(window, 'callchildfunc');
        var spy2 = sinon.spy(window, 'childfunc2');
        parent(2);
        expect(spy1).to.have.been.called();
        expect(spy2).to.have.been.called();
        // or
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy1);
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy1);

    });
});
```

After running the test always I am getting this error.

```
AssertError: expected childfunc2 to be called once but was called 0 times
```

Also If I change the test file and call the spy function then it will work.

```
var spy1 = sinon.spy(window, 'callchildfunc');
var spy2 = sinon.spy(window, 'childfunc2');
parent(2);
// After addding these below 2 lines.
window.childfunc2();
window.callchildfunc();
```

Any help?

Comment: What environment are you running this test in?

Comment: I am testing on local environment @ Mikael Lennholm

Comment: Are you running it in a browser or in a NodeJS runtime?

Comment: I am running from command prompt. This is front-end side code testing. @Mikael Lennholm

Comment: OK, are you using some kind of webdriver then? What's the command you're running? If it's `npm test`, what does the `test` script in *package.json* execute?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I am using webpack and using grunt I am running this command. grunt test:unit. Yeah I am running through grunt.

Comment: Since you're not running it in a browser, my expectation would be that you got an error saying `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. The fact that you get a different error is confusing to me. I think you need to add more information about your setup but I'm not sure I'll be able to help you, sorry.

Comment: As @MikaelLennholm says you should get a 'Reference error: window is not defined' error. 

Export your script file into a module, require it in the unit test and pass the name of the module instead of window.

Comment: @Henry Please refer to the answer for the solution

Comment: @MikaelLennholm : Sorry about that. Window object I am assigning to consider it as a global level.

Comment: @rjv : Sorry man. I forget to add like from script.js file. I am exporting like this and it is not working.                                         
  module.exports = new testFunctions();

function testFunctions() {childfunc2: childfunc2, callchildfunc: callchildfunc, parent: parent}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Script.js 

module.exports= {
childfunc2:function(){
    console.log("child function without return");
},
callchildfunc:function(var1, var2){
   return var1 + var2;
},
parent:function(x){
   var getreturnval = this.callchildfunc(x, 1);
   console.log(getreturnval);
   this.childfunc2();
}
};
```

// Test.js

```
var sinon= require('sinon'), expect=require('chai').expect
var r= require('./functests')
describe('Test for parent() function ', function(){
   it('should make parent call ', function(){
        var spy1 = sinon.spy(r, 'callchildfunc');
        var spy2 = sinon.spy(r, 'childfunc2');
        r.parent(2);
//        expect(spy1).to.have.been.called();
  //      expect(spy2).to.have.been.called();
        // or
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy1);
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy1);

    });
});
```

// Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Sorry man. I forget to add like from script.js file. I am exporting like this and it is not working. module.exports = new testFunctions(); function testFunctions() {childfunc2: childfunc2, callchildfunc: callchildfunc, parent: parent}

Comment: Why don't you simply export the module as in the code that I have posted?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Consider I have more than 30 functions in one file. Is that good practice to wrap all dependent functions in module exports? So let's say I will have 7-8 module.exports object and each containing 4-5 dependent functions. Or another way simply wrap all functions in one module.exports? What will be the best practices?

Comment: That is an altogether different question and different context. If your question is resolved, mark this as an accepted answer and ask this as a new question.